# What is the best case of quicksort for O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, complexity-theory, quicksort, dutch-national-flag-problem

Could you explain how to do quicksort for O(N) in the best case? And why will there be O(N)?

Comment: Wikipedia explains it well. Please perform some research before asking. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Best-case_analysis

Answer (score 2):

Quicksort's best case is `O(nlogn)`. When you use 3-way quicksort, the best case is O(n).

Suppose an array in which every element of it is equal. Based on [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/3-way-quicksort-dutch-national-flag/) implementation in c++, The `partition` function will be called just for one time, Because all elements are placed at the middle partition, equal to the pivot, and then the future calls of quicksort function will not be satisfied the `if` condition.